# correct way to define conditional component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I am not sure whether I am using correct approach to define conditional component,below is the code,please help me

I am invoking IIFE, which would evaluate at every state change and I don't know whether I am doing is the standard approach to create such component

I have different button which open to different dialog box,so to reuse the code I used this approach so on every different condition,it opens different dialog content and my state lives in some other component let say in dialogcomp.js .Please help me with the approach and way to create such component

> dialogcomp.js

```
<DialogComp handleClose={this.handleClose} {...this.state} loader={loader} >
  {(() => {
    switch (this.state.dialog) {
        case "case1": return <comp1 list=list} />;
        case "case2": return <comp2 list={list2}/>;
        default: return null;
    }
  })()}
</DialogComp>
```

> dialogcont.js

```
const Dialog = (props) => {

return (
    <DialogComp open={props.open} onClose={props.handleClose} aria- 
           labelledby="form-dialog-title" fullScreen>
      <AppBar className="position-relative">
          <Toolbar>
              <IconButton onClick={props.handleClose} aria-label="Close">
                  <CloseIcon />
              </IconButton>
               <Typography
                    type="title"
                    color="inherit"
                    style={{
                        flex: 1
                    }}
                >
               {props.dialog ? props.dialog.toString().replace(/\_/g,' ') : `-`} 
        </Typography>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>

    <DialogContent className="pt-3">
            {props.loader ? `Loading` : props.children}
    </DialogContent>
   </DialogComp>
);
};
```

Comment: could you please be more specific and clearly about where the error is or what are you trying to do?

Comment: there is no error it works fine but i wanted the correct approach to create such component

Comment: As long as each sub component is keyed, then yes this is fine for creating dynamic content

Comment: Think that, there isn't any approach more correct than others. There are many ways to make your code functional. At the end the important thing is that the code muss to be readable and understable for you and other persons.

Comment: I think what you're doing is just fine.

Comment: ok but i didnt get `each sub component is keyed`,what do you mean by this?

Comment: `key` property should be used with arrays of components or multiple elements of the same type, not this case IMHO